# Blurring behind CALayer OSX

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview, blur

I am trying to create a custom `NSView` that blurs any content underneath it. This is my working code:

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = YES;
self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = YES;

CIFilter *saturationFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
[saturationFilter setDefaults];
[saturationFilter setValue:@2.0 forKey:@"inputSaturation"];

CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[blurFilter setDefaults];
[blurFilter setValue:@1.0 forKey:@"inputRadius"];

self.layer.backgroundFilters = @[saturationFilter, blurFilter];

[self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Which has absolutely no effect.

If I add an image to the contents of the layer like so:

```
self.layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Icon_Red"];
```

and change the line: `self.layer.backgroundFilters = ...` to: `self.layer.filters = ...` I get a nice blur effect, exactly what I'm looking for.

Why is one working and the other not?

P.S. `NSVisualEffectView` doesn't offer the kind of control I'm looking for.

Comment: In the past (ie years ago) the only way I found to do this was by faking it. I had to create an image from the super view clipped to the views bounds then apply the effects to the image. I'm hoping somebody answers this so I can see how to do it properly.